# Powershell if -notlike issue

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0

I am trying to check a list of computer and see if what patches they are missing, this is been giving me trouble for some reason. I'm sure im overlooking something simple but help would be greatly appreciated please and thank you.

```
$Computers = "TrinityTechCorp"
$HotFixes = Get-Content HotFixes.csv

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $Comparison = get-hotfix -ComputerName $Computer | Select HotFixID
    ForEach ($HotFix in $HotFixes) {
        IF ($Comparison -NotLike "*$HotFix*") {
            Write-Host "$Computer missing $HotFix"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What trouble? Please read the question and see for yourself what you understand from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From

```
$Comparison = get-hotfix -ComputerName $Computer | Select HotFixID
```

`$Comparison` will be collection of objects with `HotFixId` properties.

If you want them as a collection of strings, you have to do:

```
$Comparison = get-hotfix -ComputerName $Computer | Select -expand HotFixID
```

Comment: Thank you, never seen the select -expand before.